# MySQL - How do I update the decimal column to allow more digits?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, decimal, alter-table

I'm a beginner in MySQL, and I accidentally created a table with a column named

```
(price decimal(2,2));
```

It needs to be `decimal(4,2)` to allow 4 digits. Since I've already created it, what is the easiest way to update that decimal value to `decimal(4,2)`? Or do I need to drop that column completely, and re-create it with the correct numbers?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY COLUMN mycolumn newtype
```

example:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTableNameHere MODIFY COLUMN YourColumnNameHere decimal(4,2)
```

Answer (score 14):

Just `ALTER TABLE` with the `MODIFY` command:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY `price` DECIMAL(4,2)
```

This would allow for 2 decimals and 2 full numbers (up to `99.99`). If you want 4 full numbers, use `6,2` instead (which would allow up to `9999.99`).

Comment: I'm reading this because I fell for the bottom part. Read the docs! Thanks for explaining that aspect of decimal. I'm sure it catches a lot of people out.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a matter of 'UPDATE' it's a matter of changing your table's structure. For that, use [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) with `MODIFY` clause:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTableName MODIFY COLUMN price DECIMAL(4,2);
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dce82/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

use *CHANGE*

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE OLD_COLUMN_NAME OLD_COLUMN_NAME datatype;
```

**an example**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE price price decimal(4,2);
```

Comment: Could you explain why is it better/same than MODIFY?

Answer (score -1):

You can change it dynamically:-

```
ALTER TABLE ".$row["table_name"]." MODIFY ".$row1["Field"]." decimal(".$rdataType[0].",".$increaseValue.")
```

For more info:

[Repository](https://github.com/nazmuljuit/DB_Table_Schema_Changer)