# How do I get decimal values?

Tags: php, html, database, phpmyadmin, decimal

I have two columns on my database, sickleave and vacationleave. It has to be a decimal but for some reason I only get the whole number. For example, I input 1.50, when I press update I get the value 2. I tried setting the column type to decimal but I still get the same result.

Here's my database schema:

[image: Schema]

Comment: change `decimal(11,0)` to something like `decimal(11,1)` .. depends on how precise you want to store your data

Comment: @B001 I tried that, when I hit save it goes back to 11,0

Answer (score 1):

From the mysql documentation:

The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column is DECIMAL(M,D). The ranges of values for the arguments are as follows:

1. M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1 to 65.
2. D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the
   scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

So in your case: hit `change` button there and in the Length/value column there should be: `11,2` with no parentheses or anything else when you hit save

In case you want to do it manually there's a discussion of it here: [MySQL - How do I update the decimal column to allow more digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773164/mysql-how-do-i-update-the-decimal-column-to-allow-more-digits)

And here's the alter: `ALTER TABLE YourTableName MODIFY COLUMN column_name DECIMAL(11,2);`

Comment: I understand but when I tried to change it, it goes back to 11,0

Comment: I tested the situation and when you hit edit add "11,2" NOTHING else in the length/value column then hit save

Comment: I did put 11,2 and nothing else, I still get 11,0. Weird.

Comment: Another reason could be that you have values that can't be converted into it there. So if you don't have any data in there that you'd like to keep empty the rows with wrong information that could help

Comment: ALTER TABLE YourTableName MODIFY COLUMN price DECIMAL(4,2);

Comment: Yep that worked out. You just have to do it manually. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tried altering it manually using:

```html
ALTER TABLE YourTableName MODIFY COLUMN price DECIMAL(4,2);
```

Thanks @user3647971