# Can anyone help me finding out what's wrong with my code?

Tags: mysql, sql

```sql
ALTER TABLE Product ALTER COLUMN weight decimal (5,2);
```

I tried using (2,1) and MySQL was unable to store the value 12.0 and gave the error message that the entered value was out of the range of weight so I tried increasing its range with the above mentioned query and it is showing a problem with `decimal (5,2)` part.

Comment: I'm assuming that replacing `ALTER COLUMN` with `MODIFY COLUMN` should fix the issue, because that's how the mysql dialect expects the alter table statement to work.

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773164/mysql-how-do-i-update-the-decimal-column-to-allow-more-digits

Comment: you're a saviour, I was going crazy over this silly thing. Thanks a lot.